# Can every separable Banach space be isometrically embedded in $l^2$ ? Or at least in $l^p$ for some $1\le p<\infty$?

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, isometry, separable-spaces

Can every separable Banach space be isometrically embedded in $l^2$ ? Or at least in $l^p$ for some $1\le p<\infty$ ?

I only know that any separable Banach space is isometrically isomorphic to a linear subspace of $l^{\infty}$.

Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: The $\ell_p$ spaces for $1\leq p <\infty$ have the property that every infinite dimensional subspace of them contains a further subspace which is isomorphic to the original space. Also $c_0$ shares the same property. Tsirelson (1974) constructed a separable reflexive space which contains no isomorphic copy of any $\ell_p$ space for $1\leq p<\infty$, nor of $c_0$. Combining these two results, you can deduce that Tsirelson's space can't be isomorphically embedded in $c_0$, nor in any $\ell_p$, for $1\leq p<\infty$.

Comment: Since you are interested in isometric embeddings, maybe you can find a simpler counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. Every closed subspace of $\ell_2$ is isometric to some Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

$c_0$ does not embed in $\ell_p$ for $1\leqslant p<\infty$ as it is not weakly sequentially complete.